# How to retrieve email addressess of users with specific role in WordPress through this code

Tags: wordpress, role

I am able to retrieve email addresses of all the users in WordPress with the help of this code:

```
<?php
$users = get_users();
foreach ($users as $user ) { 
$email = get_user_meta($user->ID, "email", true);
?>
```

I would like to retrieve the email addresses of users only with Subscriber role (slug = subscriber) by modifying the above code.

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`get_users()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) allows you to query by a specific role:

```
$users = get_users( array( 'role' => 'subscriber' ) );
foreach ( $users as $user ) { 
   $email = get_user_meta($user->ID, "email", true);
   echo $email;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code:

```
<?php
$users = get_users();
foreach ($users as $user ) { 
    if ( in_array( 'subscriber', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
        $email = get_user_meta($user->ID, "email", true);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a combination of [`get_users()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/) and [`wp_list_pluck()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pluck/). It looks like this:

```
$users = get_users( array( 'role' => 'subscriber' ) );
if( ! empty( $users ) ) {
    $emails = wp_list_pluck( $users, 'user_email' );
}
```